# Why are not mp4 videos playing in chrome using the anchor t

Tags: javascript, html

I have used the following code to display the video. some random downloaded video is playing but the video which I made is not playing.

`<a href="~/Content/videos/movie.mp4" media="video"/>`

Answer (score 2):

That is not a right way for displaying video on html. According to your code you just linked a video file.

You may use..

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Be careful about the src.

Comment: But the same tag is working with another video, but for this. And the video tag is not fitting in to my design.                                                                                                   ` <img src="~/Content/images/KB.jpg" style="width:400px; height:350px"/>
<a href="~/Content/videos/KBSearch.mp4" media="video" class="portfolio-img">
 <div class="grid_item_overlay">
  <div class="separator4"></div>
<h3 style="color:#000000; font-family:GT-Walsheim-Bold">KB Search</h3>
  </div>
</a>`

Comment: Then there is a possibility of missing  proper href.